Maven wrapper command(mvnw.cmd) failure
At DOS CMD prompt, I ran 'mvnw.cmd' as shown below.
However, I had a hard to interpret error - my partial Window user home directory pathname is being treated as a command.
That is, my home directory is "C:\Users\Jongbum Park", wrong command recognition is "C:\Users\Jongbum". Please, refer the screen capture shown below:


Is the mvnw.cmd in the same directory?

Yes, mvnw.cmd is in the same directory.
